# on scrolling some of the recyclerview's items disappear

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Trying to build an Image Editing app.I'm Using RecyclerView in horizontal fashion for showing thumbnail of images.On startup all thumbnails are shown properly but when scrolled some of the thumbnails are not visible.The thumbnails shows color effects which is implemented using Picasso Transformations library.

**xml**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlBottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flPhoto"
        android:background="@color/grey"/>
```

**Adapter class**

```
    public class FiltersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Type> mDataSet;
    private Uri selectedPhoto;

    public enum Type {
        Grayscale,
        Sepia,
        Contrast,
        Invert,
        Pixel,
        Sketch,
        Swirl,
        Brightness,
        Kuawahara,
        Vignette
    }

    public FiltersAdapter(Context context, List<Type> dataSet, Uri selectedPhoto) {
        mContext = context;
        mDataSet = dataSet;
        this.selectedPhoto = selectedPhoto;
    }

    @Override
    public FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (mDataSet.get(position)) {

            case Grayscale:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new GrayscaleTransformation())
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Sepia:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new SepiaFilterTransformation(mContext))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Contrast:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new ContrastFilterTransformation(mContext, 2.0f))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Invert:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new InvertFilterTransformation(mContext))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Pixel:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new PixelationFilterTransformation(mContext, 20))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Sketch:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new SketchFilterTransformation(mContext))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Swirl:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new SwirlFilterTransformation(mContext, 0.5f, 1.0f, new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f)))
                        .into(holder.image);

                break;
            case Brightness:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new BrightnessFilterTransformation(mContext, 0.5f))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Kuawahara:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new KuwaharaFilterTransformation(mContext, 25))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
            case Vignette:
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(selectedPhoto)
                        .transform(new VignetteFilterTransformation(mContext, new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f),
                                new float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 0f, 0.75f))
                        .into(holder.image);
                break;
        }
        holder.title.setText(mDataSet.get(position).name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView image;
        public TextView title;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailImage);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In switch always keep default case so that if nothing is matched then it will run default case.

Answer (score 0):

use if else condition to set picture in imageView and also add default values

Comment: what's wrong with switch case?. Also can you please give code in your answer to set image using if else

Comment: you can use switch cases also but before switch cases add a default image to holder.image

Comment: now I have used a predefined image for thumbnail and it's working fine.Earlier I was using the same image which user selected from gallery, the issue was with the selected image's size I suppose.

Comment: no its not we have give a default image in listView of recycleView so that when we scroll a default image is every time and is replace by the image we want.  if my answer helped you then please accept it as an answer

Comment: I tried setting a default image to holder.image before switch case but it didn't help.